# Oracle database stops frequently (idle instance)

Tags: oracle, docker, database-administration

I have an oracle 12C database on **docker Container**.  Every time I want to use it, I cant connect. So As the First Step, I Check the Listener with *lsnrctl status*:

```
The listener supports no services

The command completed successfully
```

So I call the ORACLE_SID with the following command:

```
export ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB
```

And then I *startup* it with sqlplus and the database opens. **But after the session is terminated, I need to repeat the same process again. What could be the problem?**

ORCLCDB is written in the .bash_profile and .bash_rc even before executing the *export* command and we get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself.
All my checks were inside the container itself , Like Oracle_SID , bash_profile and etc.
But I realized that the container is *unhealthy* and the problem was solved with the *docker restart restart* command.